# Optimize query many field mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm confused about how to chose best index for my table:

Have this table:

```
Hotel
-has_1
...
-has-5
-nota_AVG
-nota_1
-nota_2
-nota_3
```

and this

```
Nota_hotel
-nota_1
-nota_2
-nota_3
-id_hotel
```

Field with name "nota_*" from hotel is update from a trigger on table Nota_hotel and this field changed frequently.

My need do some query like

```
select * from hotel where has_X = true or has_Y=true order by nota_Z
```

where my clause "WHERE" can have 1 has_X or many has_* fields in query depend on what checkbox is selected.

I want know what is best practice to put index, add for every field "nota_" a index and for fields "has_" create a single index(has_1,...,has_5) or add for every field "has_" a index too, and if have this much index is possible to strangle my MySQL server ?

```
    create table hotel(
id int primary key auto_increment,
nume varchar(255),
index hotel_nume_index(nume),
nume_oras varchar(100),
nume_zona varchar(100),
nume_tara varchar(100),
foreign key (nume_oras,nume_zona,nume_tara) references oras(nume,nume_zona,nume_tara) ON DELETE CASCADE,
descriere text,
stele int,
map_x double,
map_y double,
has_sauna TINYINT(1),
has_piscina TINYINT(1),
has_parcare TINYINT(1),
has_restaurant TINYINT(1),
has_fitness TINYINT(1),
distanta_obiectiv double,
code_api1 varchar(255),
code_api2 varchar(255),
code_api3 varchar(255),
intern TINYINT(1),
nota_hotel double,
nota_restaurant double,
nota_locatie double,
nota_conditii double,
nume_comision varchar(100),
foreign key (nume_comision) references comision(nume)
);



 create table nota_hotel(
fb_id varchar(100),
data DATETIME,
nota_restaurant double,
nota_locatie double,
nota_conditi double,
comentariu text,
nume_user varchar(255),
id_hotel int,
foreign key (id_hotel) references hotel(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Here is full definition

Comment: How about 2 create table statements to clue us in. Perhaps u need basic help with table creation

Comment: I Edit and ADD full definition, ignore rest of table, only there fields is important for moment

Comment: Thank you for edit. Perhaps it is a spoken language thing. What does nota mean and that may explain why it is a floating point numeric type

Comment: nota is someting when you rating there hotel, each row from table nota_hotal is a rating come from a user, and field nota_ from table hotel is field average from table nota_hotel , but this is updated from a trigger, i want know who is best way to add index or to split table

Comment: So hotel double rating is an average saved and indexes on hotel notaZ ratings are for quick sort by's (and nothing to do with FK). Sounds good to me

Comment: Yes but i need a fast query to find all hotel with have different value on field has_ and sort result based on my field nota_ , but if I add 8 separated index will not stay much after 1 insert or update if suppose have 100.000 registration ??

Comment: can u rephrase that a bit in the "but if I" part. And what do you currently have for indexes. if any. now it is a table scan right (slow)? how many rows in hotel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a work in progress answer. will add to it.

let's say you have 5 has_ columns, like has_restaurant, has_pool, has_pool and searches are on true types like before, as in 'it is true that it has a pool'

for starters, convert them into one column using powers of 2. let us call that `hasX` and its column value is a bit-wise OR of the below (that **are not** columns)

```
has_restaurant (2^0)   1
has_pool (2^1)   2
has_wifi (2^2)  4
has_piscina (2^3)  8
has_sauna (2^4)  16
```

so if the hotel has wifi and sauna then the hasX column will contain (at least) the bits turned on with value 20, but could contain a value of 21 (has a restaurant too). but the search was on 'i want wifi and sauna' so it finds the 21 too. it is a `mask`

so at this point we have added one index to hotel, on column `hasX`

Edit
 **I just bombed on this notion** as i assumed i could craft a bit-wise search and that seems quite impossible after reading about it. The following seems to be the best work-up

```
CREATE TABLE hotel ( 
hotel_id int primary key auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
/* some more fields... */ 
); 

CREATE TABLE hotel_flags ( 
flag_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
, description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
, PRIMARY KEY (flag_id) 
); 

**the following is the intersect table**
CREATE TABLE hotel_flags_intersect ( 
hotel_id int not null
, flag_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
, PRIMARY KEY (hotel_id, flag_id) 
, UNIQUE INDEX reverse_pk (flag_id, hotel_id) 
);
```

humbly borrowed from http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,35318,35640#msg-35640

Comment: you idea is very good, but here how can be sure if I have many field can't make a mistake to have some value from 2 different comibation columns ?

Comment: updating my answer then to your comment.

Comment: ok to answer your comment, even if bit-wise were to work that is just staring at your code long enough and pounding on it. might not seem like an answer to your comment

Comment: I was do some calculations if I use power of 2 I will take 2 combination with same value but I don't, your idea to make 1 column with index is very good and seam to have nice speed, thank you very much !

Comment: be careful testing it in your implementation, that is, if they definitely want wifi and sauna, will it pick up value 21 (that has restaurant also). if it bombs, look at bottom of my answer. good luck

Comment: Power of 2 start with 1 not 0 make it combination unique

Comment: 2^0 picks up the first bit (value 1) but u can start at 7 if you want (using an int or unsigned int). if ^0 is a problem, then there is some problem in program logic you are implementing

Comment: The `SET` datatype also uses bits like that, but under the covers.